# Ext JS library needed

Tags: javascript, extjs

I downlaoded the ExtJS liberary, but it does not contain the adapter folder.

can you provide me with a link to download the full Ext JS package/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptor is a legacy js file from when ExtJs was still based around other frameworks.

You are probably looking at the equivalent of http://www.sencha.com/learn/html-page-setup/ ,which is relevant to ExtJS 2 & 3 [Download ExtJs 3 here](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs3/download/).

ExtJS 3 will have the adaptor file etc, HOWEVER ExtJS 4 doesn't use or need one.

If your guide is using ExtJs 3, maybe use that, but remember that ExtJS 4 is the newest and greatest, and they change quite a lot each time.

[Here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture) is the official guide on how to install and use ExtJS 4.x

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/ExtJS/resources/css/ext-all.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/ExtJS/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    html:'hello world'
})</script>
```

This is pretty much how it needs to look, but again GO READ THE LEARNING CENTER! Sencha  did a ton of work on their tutorials and api docs for extjs 4, they hold your hand waaay better than i can ( http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started )

Comment: can u please provide me with simple example, even helloworld with html, javascript tags

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/

Comment: this is the same website from which i downloaded my package, but it does not has the adapter folder

Comment: What is adapter folder? What are you talking about?

Comment: That is the full download you can get. I don't know what you are looking for, but it's not a part of the original fresh install.

Comment: i'm new to ExtJs and leaarning it..in the book i'm reading there is the following:

Comment: Setting up Ext JS for the first time
In order to get Ext JS running in your browser, you need to include at least two
required JavaScript files and at least one CSS file:
'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base-debug.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js">
</script>'

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base-debug.js">   and this folder is not included in the liberary available in the website

Comment: You are looking for the debug-file. It is now located in `/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js`

Comment: You also can try 4.0.7 version (there are still some issues with newly released 4.1) - http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/ext-js-4.0.7

Comment: still theat folder "adapter" is not included and the size of this package is even smaller than the package i downloaded "ext-4.1.0-gpl"